# How to spilt a string based on two condition javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm struggling a clean way to split the below variable in the clean way

```js
var x = "3/13/20,2179,5232,17660,3/14/20,2727,6391,21157,3/15/20,3499,7798,24747,3/16/20,4632,9942,27980"
```

The above string is separated with date and it's associated value, The result of split method should result into like this

```
arr[0] =  ['3/13/20','2179','5232','17660']
arr[1] =  ['3/14/20','2727','6391','21157']
```

Looking for regex pattern which can bring the above result

I know that these will not work, is there any built-in function available to achieve this stuff

```
.split("/");
.split(",");
```

Comment: removed `google-visualization` tag, nothing to do with google charts...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split by commas which are followed by `\d+\/` (the beginning of a date), then split by commas on each item:

```js
var x = '3/13/20,2179,5232,17660,3/14/20,2727,6391,21157,3/15/20,3499,7798,24747,3/16/20,4632,9942,27980';

const arr = x
  .split(/,(?=\d+\/)/)
  .map(str => str.split(','));
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just `map` and then the index of the following elements - negating any regex...that is presuming that the data is always a date followed by three values. e.g.

```js
const x = "3/13/20,2179,5232,17660,3/14/20,2727,6391,21157,3/15/20,3499,7798,24747,3/16/20,4632,9942,27980";

const b = x.split(",")
    .map((e, i, a) => !(i % 4) && [e, a[i + 1], a[i + 2], a[i + 3]])
    .filter(Boolean);

console.log(b);
```